# Symfony 1.4 setter type double precision

Tags: mysql, double, precision, setter, symfony-1.4

I want to save a number with 14 decimal places, but symfony only saves 6. How can I control this:

```
$loc->setSinRadLon(0.73946213661883);
```

In the schema the column looks like:

```
sin_rad_lon: { type: double(), scale: 14, notnull: true }
```

The DB stetting is:

```
sin_rad_lon     double(18,14)
```

In the DB the column value is: **0.73946200000000** (8 numbers are cut).

(I just tried *ini_set("precision", "14")* but it does not solve all problems.)

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 2):

try to change at your schema the "length" of the datatype for example type: double(X), scale: Y